# Simple API request not working - 403 error

Tags: perl, get

I am trying to run a simple API request from a perl script. But it seems not working. Same request if copied to web browser works without any problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $query = 'http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9944384761';

my $result = get($query);
print $result."\n";
```

when I use `getprint($query)` - it gives 403 error.

Comment: The user agent string Perl uses is probably blocked. You can get around this issue by changing it to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the body of the response (i.e. not only at the status code 403) you will find:

> The owner of this website (checkdnd.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (2f988642c0f02798-ua22).

This means that it is blocking the client because it probably looks too much like a non-browser. For this site a simple fix is to include some User-Agent header. The following works for me:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->default_header('User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0');
my $resp = $ua->get('http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9944384761');
my $result = $resp->decoded_content;
```

The site in question seems to be served by Cloudflare which has some thing they call "Browser Integrity Check". From the [support page for this feature](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-What-does-the-Browser-Integrity-Check-do-):

> ... looks for common HTTP headers abused most commonly by spammers and denies access to your page.  It will also challenge visitors that do not have a user agent **or a non standard user agent** (also commonly used by abuse bots, crawlers or visitors).

Comment: Maybe add that the reason behind this is, that the default user agent (`libwww-perl`) was/is used by crackers, and blocking it is a simple way to prevent the simplest attacks.

Comment: @grooveplex: I'm not sure if this is the reason. Variations of the "Mozilla/..." user agent are also used in malware etc - far less than libwww-perl. It's more like they block everything which is too far away from a browsers user agent.